# Given a partition of a field, construct a partition of its extension

Tags: set-theory, fields, transcendental-number-theory, continuum-hypothesis

The motivation for my question is the following algebraic consequence of the Continuum Hypothesis ($2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$) by Zoli:

(**T1**) Assume the Continuum Hypothesis holds. Then $\mathbb{R}^{\operatorname{tr}}:=\mathbb{R}\setminus\ \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ can be partitioned into countably many algebraically independent (over $\mathbb{Q}$) sets.

For later it is important to note an earlier "linear" result due to Erdős and Kakutani:

(**T2**) Assume the Continuum Hypothesis holds. Then $\mathbb{R}^*:=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ can be partitioned into countably many $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent sets.

Now the first version of my question would be as follows. Suppose we have extensions of fields $\mathbb{K}\subset\mathbb{L}\subset\mathbb{C}$ such that $|\mathbb{K}|=\mathfrak{c}$ and $\mathbb{L}/\mathbb{K}$ is algebraic. Assume that $\mathbb{K}^{\operatorname{tr}}$ can be partitioned into $\kappa$ many algebraically independent sets (in such a case we will say that $\mathbb{K}$ admits a $\kappa$*-partition*). Can $\mathbb{L}^{\operatorname{tr}}$ be partitioned in such a way as well?

However, **T1** is just a special case of a much more powerful theorem:

(**T1'**) Let $\mathbb{L}$ be a field such that $|\mathbb{L}|=\mathbb{c}$. Then $\mathfrak{c}\leq\kappa^+$ if and only if $\mathbb{L}$ admits a $\kappa$-partition.

(We have analogous result **T2'** for the linear case. I also think that the cardinal number $\mathfrak{c}$ can be changed to any other but let's fix it to keep things simple.)

In the context of the above question it now follows that $\mathbb{K}$ admits a $\kappa$-partition $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathfrak{c}\leq\kappa^+\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathbb{L}$ admits a $\kappa$-partition, since $|\mathbb{L}|=\mathfrak{c}$ as well. Note that this works for *any* field $\mathbb{L}$ containing $\mathbb{K}$.

So my question is actually this: assume that we have extensions of fields $\mathbb{K}\subset\mathbb{L}\subset\mathbb{C}$, $|\mathbb{K}|=\mathfrak{c}$, and a $\kappa$-partition $\mathbb{K}=\displaystyle\bigcup_{\lambda<\kappa}A_\lambda$. Can we *construct* a $\kappa$-partition of $\mathbb{L}$ from $\{A_\lambda\}_{\lambda<\kappa}$? Of course there is *some* $\kappa$-partition of $\mathbb{L}$ by **T1'**. But this partition is *a priori* in no way connected to the partition of $\mathbb{K}$. In the linear case we have an inclusion of $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces $V\subset W$ with $\dim V=\dim W=\mathfrak{c}$; hence there is a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear isomorphism $f:V\rightarrow W$. Then a $\kappa$-partition $A_\lambda$ of $V$ gives a $\kappa$-partition $f(A_\lambda)$ of $W$. This uses Axiom of Choice, so one may object to calling it a "construction", but at least the new partition is in some way built from that of $V$. So my (a little vague question) is: can something similar be done for the algebraic case?

To end with some "precise" questions. Let $\mathbb{K}\subset\mathbb{L}\subset\mathbb{C}$ be extensions of fields, all with the same cardinality, and assume that we are given a $\kappa$-partition $\mathbb{K}=\displaystyle\bigcup_{\lambda<\kappa}A_\lambda$. In what follows by "constructed" I mean an explicit construction, preferably but not necessarily without using AC. The linear example was an attempt to show that I do not exclude "constructions" depending crucially on AC but "explicit" in some other way.

**(Q1)** Can a $\kappa$-partition of $\mathbb{L}$ be "constructed" from $\{A_\lambda\}_{\lambda<\kappa}$?

**(Q2)** What if we assume that $\mathbb{L}/\mathbb{K}$ is finite (algebraic, finitely generated, ...)?

**(Q3)** What about perhaps the most natural case $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{L}=\mathbb{C}$?